# Express.js cannot access static files even after configuring express.static

Tags: node.js, express

I tried localhost:3000/index.html (where I put a static page), localhost:3000/javascripts/dio.js (where I put js)
localhost:3000/images/dio1.jpg (where I put the images),
All cannot be accessed. Why? What is wrong?

My app.js define:

```
var express = require('express')
var app=express()
app.bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
app.im=require('imagemagick')
app.fs=require('fs')
app.application_root = __dirname
app.path = require("path")
app.mongoose = require("mongoose")

var config=require('./config.js')(app,express)

var models = require('./models/models.js')(app.mongoose)
models.UserModel = models.UserModel
models.CommentModel = models.CommentModel
models.ItemModel = models.ItemModel

require('./routes')(app, models)

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000")
```

Here is my config.js define:

```
module.exports = function(app, express, mongoose){
    var config=this

    app.configure(function (){
        app.set('views',__dirname+'/views')
        app.set('view engine','jade')
        app.set('view engine', {layout:true})

        app.use(express.bodyParser())
        app.use(express.methodOverride())
        app.use(express.cookieParser())
        app.use(express.session({secret: 'topsecret',store: new express.session.MemoryStore}))
        app.use(app.router)
        app.use(express.static(app.path.join(app.application_root+"public")))
        app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions:true,showStack:true}))
        app.use(express.bodyParser({keepExtensions: true, uploadDir:"./public/uploads"}))
    })

    /*DB part:*/
    app.mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dio_database')

    return config
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating *and* joining:

```
 app.path.join(app.application_root+"public")
```

Either each part should be passed as a separate argument to [`path.join`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2):

```
 app.path.join(app.application_root, "public")
```

Or, if you'd rather concatenate, [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) won't have a trailing slash for `application_root`, so you'll need to add one:

```
 app.application_root + '/public'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this style:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```